# Accessing a Property's Value?

Tags: powershell

Just starting on Powershell and cannot find a way around it. Any help greatly appreciated. Just trying to access the Property -> Version to get just the numeric result.

So from the code below i would only want  **4.5.51650**

```
Get-Childitem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full


Name                           Property
----                           --------
1033                           Version       : 4.5.51650
                               CBS           : 1
                               TargetVersion : 4.0.0
                               Install       : 1
                               Servicing     : 0
                               Release       : 379893
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full').Version
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Get-childItem` and `Foreach-Object` because there can be several version installed:

```
Get-Childitem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' | Foreach-Object {$_.GetValue('Version')}
```